# How to export table structure with PhpMyAdmin 4.3.10 like with 4.1.14

Tags: phpmyadmin, export, structure

With PhpMyAdmin 4.3.10 (And a little before), an export of a table structure is like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_apprentis`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_apprentis` (
  `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL,
  `a_promo_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_cursus` smallint(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `test_apprentis`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`);
ALTER TABLE `test_apprentis`
  MODIFY `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3665;
```

With three parts:
- Create table
- Alter table for primary key
- Alter table for auto-increment.

With PhpMyAdmin 4.1.14 (and before), an export of table structure is like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_apprentis`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_apprentis` (
  `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_promo_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_cursus` smallint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3665 ;
```

With only one query that has all parameters.

Why is it not possible to have the same with PhpMyAdmin 4.3.10?

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is that phpMyAdmin changed the format of the generated export, I believe this was done to optimize the import but I'm not 100% sure about this. If you have a reason this doesn't work as well for you, the best thing to do is open a feature request at http://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/